# Laplace domain band-pass filter equivalent to Matlab 2nd order butterworth filter

Tags: matlab, math, filter, frequency

I am trying to build a bandpass filter analytically with the following specification:

1. Center frequency of fc (say 16hz)
2. Pass bandwidth of fb (say 2hz.  therefore, cut-off frequencies are 15 and 176hz)
3. 0 dB in the pass bandwidth

The hope is to develop one that matches the one generated by the following code:

```
freq_Plox = 16;% [Hz]
freq_sepa = 1; % separation width
ord       = 2; % butterworth filter order
wc_bpf_lp = 2*pi*(freq_Plox - freq_sepa);
wc_bpf_hp = 2*pi*(freq_Plox + freq_sepa);
dt = 1/1000;

[num_bpf,den_bpf] = butter(ord,(2*dt)/(2*pi)*[wc_bpf_lp wc_bpf_hp],'bandpass');
opts = bodeoptions;
opts.PhaseWrapping = 'on';
opts.FreqUnits = 'Hz';

figure;bode(tf(num_bpf,den_bpf,dt_mec_di),opts);grid on;hold on;
```

Without a good textbook on filters, i resorted to web search and none of the formulas has worked.  Please, help.

Comment: Please explain your problem better. Why don't you use exactly that code? What part do you need to change? And why change at all it if you want the same result?

Comment: @LuisMendo, thank you for the question.  Yes, this will eventually be implemented in a C code where butter is not available.  Once I have a continuous transfer function, then, I can convert it to its corresponding discrete transfer function, and then finally the difference function.  It's just that wc varies and I need to move the band-pass filter around as it does.

Comment: Eric, this is an interesting question, but you might a more suitable audience for it at electronics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @RobertDodier Thank you.  I didn't know there is a separate forum.  Someone helped me with the 0 dB gain and it's Kpb = Kpb = (Q^2*wh^2 + wl*(-2*Q^2 +1)*wh + Q^2*wl^2)/(Q^2*wh^2).  My next question is why there is a slight different between the two filters: mine and Matlab.  They are so close to each other leading me to think that it might be an additional or slightly different treatment rather than a different formula altogether, but maybe Matlab butter does use a different formula.  Do you know?

Comment: I don't know, but you might be able to investigate by looking at the Matlab's code for the filter. A lot of user-visible functions are implemented as `.m` files which are shipped with the installation package, if I'm not mistaken, so you may be able to study their implementation and see how they did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fc = 16; %[Hz], center frequency
fb = 1;  %[Hz], ±pass bandwidth
fl = fc - fb; %[Hz], low cutoff frequency
fh = fc + fb; %[Hz], high cutoff frequency
Q  = fc / (fh - fl); % quality factor

% cascade 4th order
wc = 2*pi*fc; %[rad/sec]
wl = 2*pi*fl; %[rad/sec]
wh = 2*pi*fh; %[rad/sec]

Kpb = (Q^2*wh^2 + wl*(-2*Q^2 +1)*wh + Q^2*wl^2)/(Q^2*wh^2);
Hs  = Kpb* wh^2/(s^2 + (wh/Q)*s + wh^2) * s^2/(s^2 + (wl/Q)*s + wl^2);
```